# Free NginX alternative with max_conns for upstream

Tags: web-server

Is there any free nginx alternative that has {simple configuration}, {similar performance}, {gzipping output on the fly}, {multiple backend} but with [max_conns](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html) directive (because we need to limit number of access to our slower backend)?

I found few alternative, but it doesn't seems support connection limiting to upstream/backend:

- Lighttpd http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy
- Cherokee http://cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_proxy.html
- Varnish https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-backends.html
- Caddy https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy

Answer (score 1):

Apache supports advanced load balancing.
I dont know if it works (and anybody tested and if worked please comment and say it works) cause I am now reading about it, but in
http://www.jimjag.com/presos/AC-US-08/ACUS08-AdvancedLoadBalancing-Apache2.2.pdf
at the slide 22 says that you could use:

```
<Proxy balancer://foo>
 BalancerMember http://www1.example.com:80/ loadfactor=1
 BalancerMember http://www3.example.com:80/ loadfactor=1
 BalancerMember http://www2.example.com:80/ loadfactor=4 status=+h
 ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>
```

something like this and you notice there is `loadfactor` I think it is what you are looking for.

There is another option, at slide 31 it says there is `max`, `min`, `smax` parameters which are:

> **connection pool:**
>   – min
>   • Initial number of connections [0]
>   – max
>   • Hard maximum number of connections [1|TPC]
>   – smax:
>   • soft max - keep this number available [max]

And again if someone (or you yourself) tested it and worked properly please comment out and tell me to change this answer to tell others that its working.
Thanks.